# SugarCRM: how to get all contacts for an account via REST API

Tags: sugarcrm

I am trying to get all contacts for a particular account (i know the account id) from SugarCRM using the v2 REST API.

I am sending a GET request with the following parameters:

```
input_type => 'JSON'

response_type => 'JSON'

method => 'get_entry_list'

rest_data => '{session:"some-valid-session-id", module_name:"Contacts", query:"contacts.account_id=some-valid-id"}'
```

I expect to get all contacts that are related to this accoutn, but instead I get an error "... MySQL error 1054: Unknown column 'contacts.account_id' in 'where clause'"

However, when I try to get all contacts without providing any query (query='') I get all the contacts with all their properties and I can see that there is an account_id property.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete code example, including the entrypoint you are using? Thanks!

Comment: Oops, it is atually v2 of the rest interface. Correcting the question.

Comment: Entry point is http://server-name-here.com/service/v2/rest.php

Comment: Can't really provide a code example since I am doing this directly from REST Console (a Google Chrome add-on). Just sending a GET HTTP request with the aforementioned parameters.

Comment: A bit more info: when I send the request with rest_data => {session:"some-valid-session-id", module_name: "Contacts", query:"", order_by:"", offset:"", select_fields:["account_id"]} I get list of contacts with only their account_id property in the name_values_list. So obviously countact account_id is somehow accessible.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058572/sugarcrm-rest-api-how-to-get-contacts-related-to-an-account). it helped me to solve similar type of problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `query:"accounts.id=some-valid-id"`.

It has worked for me in the past with the `SOAP API`.

Comment: @babbata try `rest_data => '{session:"some-valid-session-id", module_name:"Accounts", query:"accounts.id=some-valid-id", link_name_to_fields_array:[{name:"contacts", value:['id', 'name']}]}'`. you should get the account for the given id and its related contacts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. This method worked, but not before some tweaking. There is something wrong with the REST API implementation (at least v2) - parameters behave as if they are handled by order and not by name, although they are named. So the rest_data you suggest did not work right away. I had to add all parameters of the get_entry_list like that: {session:"valid-sess", module_name:"Accounts", query:"accounts.id='valid-id'", order_by:'', offset:'0', select_fields:['id', 'name'], link_name_to_fields_array:[{name:"contacts", value:['id', 'first_name']}]}. This works (continued...)

Comment: (...continued) Btw, 'name' is not a field in Contacts hence the use of 'first_name'. All in all I must say that the REST API is very poorly designed, implemented, documented and obviously undertested. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my method.  It uses this wrapper class: http://github.com/asakusuma/SugarCRM-REST-API-Wrapper-Class/

```
/**
 * returns an array of contacts that are related to the accountId passed as a param.
 * The array returned will be an array of associative arrays.
 * @param $accountId
 * @param array $contactSelectFields optional sets the different items to return, default includes id, email1, name, title, phone_work, and description
 * @return array
 *
 */
public function getAllContactsAtOrganization( $accountId, $contactSelectFields=array("id", "email1", "name", "title", "phone_work", "description")) {

    $sugar = new Sugar_REST( SUGAR_REST_URL, SUGAR_USER_NAME, SUGAR_PASSWORD);

    $fields = array( "Accounts" => array("id", "name"),
        "Contacts" =>  $contactSelectFields);
    $options = array(
        'where' => "accounts.id='$accountId'"
    );
    $apiResult = $sugar->get_with_related("Accounts", $fields, $options );


    $contacts = array();
    foreach( $apiResult['relationship_list'][0]['link_list'][0]['records'] as $almostContact) {
        $curr = array();
        foreach($contactSelectFields as $key) {
            $curr[$key] = $almostContact['link_value'][$key]['value'];
        }
        $contacts[] = $curr;
    }

    //print_r($contacts);

    return $contacts;
}
```

### Sample Return

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 47e1376c-3029-fc42-5ae2-51aeead1041b
            [email1] => johndoe@gmail.com
            [name] => Blake Robertson
            [title] => CTO
            [phone_work] => 8881112222 
            [description] => Opinionated developer that hates SugarCRM's REST API with a passion!
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4c8e3fcf-8e69-ed7d-e239-51a8efa4f530
            [email1] => csmith@mailinator.com
            [name] => Carolyn Smith
            [title] => Director of Something
            [phone_work] => 832-211-2222
            [description] => She's a smooth operator...
        )
)
```

### For Reference Purposes

#### Here's the "rest-data" (nicely formatted)

Used print_r of the php array

```
Array
(
    [session] => 9j7fm4268l0aqm25kvf9v567t3
    [module_name] => Accounts
    [query] => accounts.id='e583715b-7168-5d61-5fb1-513510b39705'
    [order_by] => 
    [offset] => 0
    [select_fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => id
            [1] => name
        )

    [link_name_to_fields_array] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => contacts
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => id
                            [1] => email1
                            [2] => name
                            [3] => title
                            [4] => phone_work
                            [5] => description
                        )

                )

        )

    [max_results] => 20
    [deleted] => FALSE
)
```

#### Post Body

> method=get_entry_list&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&rest_data={"session":"iov5a257lk5acsg9l3ll6kuej3","module_name":"Accounts","query":"accounts.id='e583715b-7168-5d61-5fb1-513510b39705'","order_by":null,"offset":0,"select_fields":["id","name"],"link_name_to_fields_array":[{"name":"contacts","value":["id","email1","name","title","phone_work","description"]}],"max_results":20,"deleted":"FALSE"}method=logout&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&rest_data={"session":"iov5a257lk5acsg9l3ll6kuej3"}

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with SugarCRM yet, but did you try with just account_id=some-valid-id ? because I also did a REST request to add a contact to sugarcrm and I didn't mention the table's name, just the fields. I didn't try this but it seems logical to me since you already mentionned the module's name, so I guess sugar kind of knows what table(s?) to look for when processing your query.

Comment: I did indeed try only account_id = some-valid-id, but I got the same error.