# SugarCRM REST API, how to get Contacts related to an Account

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am using SugarCRM Pro 6.5.5. I am trying to do some integration into another application, so I need to do some API calls from that other application. I am using the REST API v2. At this point, I need to get a Contact that is related to an Account via the account ID. I have tried both `get_relationships()` and `get_entry_list()`, but I can't get either of them to work.

Here's my input for `get_relationships()`:

`{"session":"eujfbfsfjgni98m0mivl6jm6r2","module_name":"Accounts","module_id":"c03d0649-0525-2f90-1206-50881e87d7dd","link_field_name":"contacts"}`

I have tried many variations of this, and several other options, but nothing did what I wanted. This is the output from above:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [entry_list] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 
                    [module_name] => Contacts
                    [name_value_list] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [deleted] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => deleted
                                    [value] => 0
                                )

                            [do_not_call] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => do_not_call
                                    [value] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [relationship_list] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I don't see how this information could ever be useful.

Next up, I tried `get_entry_list()` with a query to select only the Contacts that had the given account ID. Here's my input for that:

`{"session":"8mol33e7kdq6girugu30dnt074","module_name":"Contacts","query":"accounts.id = 'c03d0649-0525-2f90-1206-50881e87d7dd'"}`

I am using `accounts.id` because I have read in similar questions, that is correct. I've tried many other things, like: `contacts.account_id`, `account_id`, etc. In every case, I get a MySQL error in the log stating the column is invalid.

[SugarCRM: how to get all contacts for an account via REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615498/sugarcrm-how-to-get-all-contacts-for-an-account-via-rest-api)

This question is relevant, and seems to be the exact same problem. I tried adding a `link_name_to_fields_array` option to my input, but no matter what value I provide, it results in the following MySQL error in the log:

`AND jt11.deleted=0 where (Array) AND contacts.deleted=0: MySQL error 1054: Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'`

Dafuq?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show the code you used when trying with `link_name_to_fields_array`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to **ychaouche**, I figured it out.

I was able to use the `get_relationships()` method after all. I had tried before adding the `related_fields` to my input, but all that did was result in an empty result set. The answer? Set `related_module_query` to an empty string... and now the result set is not empty. Yep, my 3+ hours of furious Googleing last night is because of *that*.

So, here is some working code in case anyone else has this problem:

```
{
    "session": "iov9pg9kvvl60librung1h5fh6",
    "module_name": "Accounts",
    "module_id": "c03d0649-0525-2f90-1206-50881e87d7dd",
    "link_field_name": "contacts",
    "related_module_query": "",
    "related_fields": [
        "first_name",
        "last_name"
    ],
    "deleted": false
}
```

This got me the following result set:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [entry_list] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 
                    [module_name] => Contacts
                    [name_value_list] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [first_name] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => first_name
                                    [value] => John
                                )

                            [last_name] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => last_name
                                    [value] => Smith
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [relationship_list] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

You can of course specify different fields in `related_fields` and get different pieces of data.

Comment: I'm glade you made it. What a waste of time. The Soap method should ignore arguments if they're not passed as parameters, not return an empty result set. To force you to pass an empty string is just nonesense to me. This is a very strange API design.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [sugarcrm/tests/service/RESTAPI4Test.php](https://github.com/sugarcrm/sugarcrm_dev/blob/master/tests/service/RESTAPI4Test.php). It's got plenty of examples on how to use the REST API. It's a common practice to look at test code for code examples on how to use a library/framework/API. Tests are in this sense a very good documentation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't have that directory, or that file anywhere in the Sugar source. I did a regex search for any .php files containing "test" in the name, and the only slightly relevant result was `SoapTest.php` in `sugarcrm/examples`. But, that only had one very basic call to `get_entry_list()`, which doesn't help me.

Comment: I'm using 6.5.0 and it's definitely there. I don't see how they would remove it in a minor version 6.5.5. Anyway, here's a copy of it, I hope you find that useful https://gist.github.com/3952654

Comment: Thanks, that helped me figure it out. The solution was aggravatingly simple. I posted my solution in a reply.

Comment: You were right, I just downloaded the latest version of SugarCRM and the directory is not there ! pitty.